# service Application.StartupPath

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there an equivalent to Application.StartupPath when writing a service in VB2010? I would like to write some data to a simple log file in the directory where the service executable is installed at (ProgramFilesFolder Manufacturer ProductName) but since it is a service and not an application it bombs out.

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be "where is an appropriate place for a service to write logging information to?" - because I'm not sure "the same location as where the service exe lives" is correct here - nor, necessarily, is `StartupPath` the correct answer for a similar question asked about a non-service program.

Comment: Actually either is a valid question. I didn't think about putting logging information in any other place. I wanted to keep everything sorted by the different applications and services. I didn't want to use a shared folder or temp folder.